# ID this plant training strap?

Tags: identification, tools

Can anyone identify this item, tell me where I could find more. I don't even know what to call it if I were to call around to local garden shops. I got some from a friend, and he doesn't know where it came from.

We think it's some kind of strap for training plants, at least that's what we've been using it for.

It comes in long strips, and it is designed so that the ends of the chain can slide into the links and lock.

[image]

Comment: What’s “training plants”?

Comment: @dakab It's when you force a plant to grow the way you want it to grow. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espalier

Comment: @Brenn Please don't leave StackExchange (SE) from one bad experience. It's a wonderfully helpful community. Your comment was deleted automatically by software. SE has policies and procedures in place to delete innaproprite questions and comments. It's all community enforced. When a comment is flagged by enough people, the system automatically deletes it. The policy is in place so that SE does not devolve into something like Yahoo Answers. You can read more about comments at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a piece off a roll of [Chainlock Tree Ties](http://www.britishhardwood.co.uk/chainlock-tree-ties/263/), but there are many types and sizes of similar ties available, usually listed under *Tree and Shrub ties*, so suggest you Google that.

Comment: Thanks, Google lead me to some on Home Depot's web site. An alternative usage they suggested (that I wouldn't have thought of) was as ties for cabling or hose http://imgur.com/a/rsxYH .

Answer (score 0):

Same or similar to Bamboo's answer.  Simply a constraining device used for staking trees akin to plastic ties used for bundles and handcuffs.  Grins, I walk through parking lots and dismantling these things.  Staked trees are forgotten and because of the staking are the first trees to blow over.